# LXDE directory menu not working

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

My OS :  Lubuntu 14.04
LXPanel Version : 0.6.1
Installation works very well.  But the " directory menu " on the taskbar doesn't work.  When I clicked on it, it show me a list including " Desktop, Download, Documents ....  ", each has a submenu with " open, open in terminal "  When I clicked on "open" or "open in terminal", nothing happened.  What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance for answering (:

Answer (score 0):

Please right click any open space on the LXPanel.  Choose Add/Remove Panel Items.  You should find yourself under Panel Applets in Panel Preferences.  Choose Menu and then edit.  You should see

/usr/share/lubuntu/images/lubuntu-logo.png

That will get your Menu items.  It sounds like you have something else there.